# Fade in and out underline when hovering?

Tags: html, css, hover, underline

How can I make a fade in and out underline when I hover onto my links?

I can't use `border-bottom` property, because some of my links are tabs, so if I use `border-bottom`, the div gets underline and not the text. I need only the text to be underlined.

Is there a way to do that using CSS, or JS..?

**Here is the HTML I would like to add the effect in:**

```html
<div class="tabcordion">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <li class="option1 active underline"><a data-target=".KONTAKT">KONTAKT</a></li>
    <li class="option2"><a data-target=".ÜBER_UNS">ÜBER UNS</a></li>
    <li class="option3"><a data-target=".BESUCH">BESUCH</a></li>
    <li class="option4"><a data-target=".MITGLIED">MITGLIED</a></li>
    <li class="option5"><a data-target=".PROJEKTBERATUNG">PROJEKTBERATUNG</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting just the the underline to fade or all of the text? I ask because I don't think you can do just the underline the way it is.

Comment: @TylerChristian I need just the underline to fade in/out. But since my text is always black (underline or not), maybe it doesn't matter?

Comment: Well, if I understand what you are saying correctly, you would need to develop a different scheme, probably using `<hr>` or some other element to underline the text. Because if you fade the `<a>` it will do it all.

Comment: There are several ways of doing this, but it really depends on the structure of your page. If you wrap the text in a `span` or something similar,  you can add a border-bottom to that, and then `animate` that through CSS.

Comment: I think I would use `@keyframes` to set the beginning and end opacity/color. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363205/css-background-color-keyframes-animation

Comment: @TylerChristian Then I would need to set beginning and end opacity/color only on the underline. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `text-decoration` property and transition the color'

[text-decoration-color @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color)

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline solid transparent;
  transition: text-decoration 1s ease;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline solid Currentcolor;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</a>
```

Comment: It works, but only on Firefox and Chrome. Doesn't work on Safari… Is there a way to make this solution work on every browsers?

Comment: MDN indicates that Safari needs a `-webkit`prefix (no luck with IE though).

Comment: Ok ! How do I have to write the code with the `-webkit` prefix?

Comment: Use the individual properties like `text-decoration-color` There's more on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

Comment: I had a look on MDN. But when I use the prefix `-webkit-` it remove all my underlined text and hover…

Comment: exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0 ,0);
  transition: border-bottom 300ms;
}
a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">qwerty lorem</a>
```

You should use `border-bottom` and animate that by using `rgba` and altering the value for the opacity.

Comment: Yes. But I asked preferably for a not `border-bottom` solution. Because some of my links are in tabs (div) and then it underlines the div, and not the text.

Comment: Can you show some html for this as it is hard to fix a problem that can't be seen. There will be a way to do this with `border-bottom`, it is just a matter of creating a selector that works for your dom structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `pseudoelement`

```css
.tab {
  background: whitesmoke;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2em;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
}

a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <a href="#" class="underline">link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually a really smart way of doing it, since it works for divs as well as `a` tags. However, for a div you may want to `position` the pseudoelement up a little to avoid it being too low (outside the div/tab)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to do it with css text-decoration, but you could imitate it with `border-bottom`:

```css
.posts a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: border 400ms ease;
  -moz-transition: border 400ms ease;
  -ms-transition: border 400ms ease;
  -o-transition: border 400ms ease;
  transition: border 400ms ease;
}

.posts a:hover,
.posts a:active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="posts">
  <a href="#">something</a>
</div>
```