# Change Background Color & Font Color Automatically Via CSS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, keyframe

I want to achieve an animation - Where `background-color` and `color` change automatically.

Please see the GIF I created:

[image: SEE THE GIF]

I want to achieve exactly same thing

How to make this happen?

I tried already with keyframes. But in this case it's not the option

Comment: not only js, coffeescript also needed.

Comment: Have a look at [CSS animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you looking for is @keyframe.

Here is simmilar problem
[CSS background color keyframes animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363205/css-background-color-keyframes-animation)

```
@keyframes animation {
0%     {background-color:red;}
50.0%  {background-color:blue;}
100.0%  {background-color:red;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yjsh9613/

I think keyframes works pretty well for this one, here is example:
https://codepen.io/jerrykck/pen/eYZERPe

Comment: Keyframes not helping in this case